# How to show two related Datatables from one dataset in one Gridview in ASP.NET, C#?

Tags: c#, gridview, datatable, dataset

I have a dataset with two DataTables and relationship beetween Pk_FK.
Is something like a join in sql:

C# code goes as follows:

```
ds.Tables.Add(tabelaViagens);
ds.Tables.Add(tabelaViagens_Data);
ds.Relations.Add("Id_viagens", ds.Tables[0].Columns["ID_VIAGEM"], ds.Tables[1].Columns["ID_VIAGEM"]);
gvViagens.DataSource = ds;
gvViagens.DataBind();
```

However this way Gridview only displays contents for tabelaViagens.

Any idea how to get it to display both tables (related like a join)?

Comment: You're right, there isn't a "direct" way to do it. You'll have to join the tables first. Here's a helper class to get you started: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326080/en-us

Answer (score 0):

Check this out
[Display dataset data in GridView from multiple data tables](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataset/thread/f63f612f-20be-4bad-a91c-474396941800)

Comment: except for the sql statement that I wanted to avoid, the solution presented does not work. If I do 
    gvViagens.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]., it only displays content from Table[0]

Comment: http://msmvps.com/blogs/shahed/archive/2009/02/09/asp-net-tips-display-resultset-from-multiple-datatable.aspx